# node.js server and client: one or two node instances?

Tags: node.js, architecture

I am writing a website with node.js, and, until now, I've always separated the client and server parts in two different node.js instances (and processes):

- one for the server part (APIs, interaction with databases, etc.)
- one for the client part (js code is executed in the browser)

Is this the correct way of doing it? Or there is a way to collapse client and server in one node.js instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need node.js to provide clients with static files.

Nginx (or any other reverse proxy) can do it in a more efficient way thus conserving resources of you server and allowing higher loads.

I suggest you to use nginx to provide static files and forward API requests to node.js service.

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /client-code;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location @node {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```